# Using string literals types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use an method (in Angular) that has the following definition:

```
request(method: string, url: string, options?: {
    body?: any;
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    params?: HttpParams;
    observe?: HttpObserve;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<any>;
```

My code looks like this:

```
let options = {
    headers: headers,
    content: content,
    responseType: 'json'
};

 http.request(method, url, options)
```

But I get this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; content: string; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ body?: any; headers?: HttpHeaders; params?: HttpParams; observe?: HttpObserve; reportProgress?:...'. Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"text" | "json" | "arraybuffer" | "blob"'.

As reponseType doesn't have a declared type like "*type ResponseType = 'arraybuffer' | ...*", how can I "cast" the literal 'json' to be a valid value for this property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cast the string to the string literal type:

```
let options = {
    headers: headers,
    content: content,
    responseType: 'json' as 'json'
};
```

**Edit**

Since 3.4 you could also add `as const`:

```
let options = {
    headers: headers,
    content: content,
    responseType: 'json' as const
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I just also found the answer in the discussion of the issue open at  the typescript project: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11465

Comment: TypeScript 3.4 allows the following syntax: `'json' as const`. Helps with the repetition, especially for more complex types.

Comment: @p4m That is true. Updated the answer, thank you for bringing it up, as const was not in TS when I gave this answer :)